# how to activate "Cut [Command+X]" option in Mac?

Tags: mac-osx, mac, finder

I am new to OS X and one thing that is constantly bugging me is the fact that I cannot move any file in Finder. I have to copy the file and then delete the file at the source.

Can anyone help me out with a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file you want to move remains on the same volume, just drag the file from one folder to another. If you want to move the file to another volume, press and hold the Command key while dragging the file from one folder to another.

**Alternatively:**

Highlight the item(s) to be moved, and type **Command-C** (or Edit>Copy) as if to copy it. Then navigate to the destination window, and rather than pressing command-V (or Edit>Paste) , instead press **Option-Command-V**  (or hold down the option key when using the Edit menu.)  This changes "paste" into "move item here", i.e, the item will disappear from where it was copied! The result is equivalent to a "cut and paste" only safer - the source item is not removed until after it has been successfully moved elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best you could do is write a pair of Applescripts to emulate Cut and Paste and then bind them to keystrokes with Quicksilver or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The short answere is no, you can't do it the way you are used to in windows or linux. imo this is a big flaw in finder. I'd reccomend a finder plugin called [file cutter](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/29931)

Comment: FYI, the author says it doesn't work under Snow Leopard.

Answer (score -1):

To my best knowledge is "Apple+X" the way to cut a file in MacOS X

Comment: "Command" and "Apple" are the same thing, and it won't cut a file like in Windows.

Comment: My bad, I recall it working in previous versions of OS X. It may have changed or my memory does not server me as well as it used to :)